# PIN 3.0 compilation error because of '__value' symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intel-pin

I am porting my tool to PIN 3.0 using Visual c++ 2012 because I now have Windows 10. I followed the porting guide provided [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/8e/f5/PinCRT.pdf)

However, I ran into an error:

```
error C4890: '__value': use of this keyword requires the command line option: /clr:oldSyntax
```

When turning this /clr:oldSyntax option on, plus adding RTTI availability (/GR instead of /GR-) as otherwise it is not compatible with /clr:oldSyntax, I get more or less the same issue:

```
error C2059: syntax error: '__value'
```

this error is located in the file type_trait.h (header file of the PIN 3.0 Library)

```
#ifdef _STLP_STATIC_CONST_INIT_BUG
    static const bool __value;
#else
    static const bool __value = sizeof(__test<_Tp>(0)) == sizeof(__select_types::__t1);
#endif
```

Is this a common issue, and if so is there any workaround ? Or did I missed something in the porting guide ? I understand that the name __value introduced in this PIN 3.0 header is in conclict.

Comment: That code is rather brutally unfriendly to C++.  Why you'd consider compiling it with /clr in effect is very hard to guess.  You just can't.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I edited the question. I did not compiled it with /clr, but with /clr:oldSyntax, as requested by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a "bug" in visual c++ as reported [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/adabf801-8006-47bd-9495-972e04df5c78/use-of-value-as-a-variable-name-in-unmanaged-c-code?forum=vcgeneral)

The solution is to add the following preprocessor definition:

```
/D__value=_value
```